# How do I turn down an internship offer by a professor because I have a better offer in a corporate research lab?

Tags: professorship, research-undergraduate, industry, internship, research-assistantship

I applied to several corporate research labs for internships. Seeing no progress on my application, I emailed a professor in a top university asking for an internship. He was impressed by my work and agreed to accept me. Now I got an offer from a top corporate lab in my area of research. How do I politely decline the professor's offer, given that I might want to do a PhD with him in future?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just send her/him a polite e-mail saying that although you were/are very much looking forward to working with her/him, you are taking another offer right now, but wish to stay in touch:

> Dear Prof. X, I am very much looking forward to working with you.  However, at this time I have also received a placement offer at company Y, and I will go there.  I hope we can work together in the future.
>
> Best regards,
> *Firstname  Lastname.*

Or something similar.  If you are polite and honest, you should be fine.

Comment: won't he be angry on why did I even apply to work with him if I was already expecting another offer?

Comment: There's no reason to be mad. It's normal to apply to several places.

Comment: I would avoid this sentence: "I am very much looking forward to work with you" as it starts off the email as if you will accept.
I would say something like 
"Dear Prof. X, Thank you for your replies, your work looks very exciting, however, I have received a placement offer... "

Comment: @Rohit: Not as long as you were clear and honest with the professor. If you did something like clearly accept his offer, *then* back out of it, yes, he may be angry.